# Having Some Error transferring data between GridDB and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, griddb

I am facing an error while transferring data between GridDB and PostgreSQL databases.

```
// Retrieve data from GridDB and insert into PostgreSQL
RowSet<Row> rowSet = gridContainer.query("SELECT * FROM <griddb_container>");
while (rowSet.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowSet.next();
    // Retrieve values from GridDB row
    String value1 = row.getString(0);
    int value2 = row.getInteger(1);

    // Set values in the prepared statement
    insertStatement.setString(1, value1);
    insertStatement.setInt(2, value2);

    try {
        // Execute the insert statement
        insertStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error executing insert statement: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

error while executing statement

Comment: What error are you getting? Also you can refer to these blogs for migration between PostgreSQL and GridDB: https://griddb.net/en/blog/scheduling-data-migration-from-postgresql-to-griddb-using-apache-airflow/ , https://griddb.net/en/blog/using-the-griddb-import-export-tools-to-migrate-from-postgresql-to-griddb/

Comment: Thanks @Codelicious  this blog is very helpful I have sorted out the issue